# How do I get the name of a service class in Android?

Tags: android, service, android-service

How do I get the name of a service programmatically in Android?

Let's say I've this piece of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private MyService mService;
```

Let's say I want to toast the name of the service which could be like `com.example.MyService`.

Is it possible to get it from `mService` variable?

For now, I got it using `MyService` in this way

```
MyService.class.getName()
```

Comment: BTW this thats correct way...what else do you want exactly?

Comment: Are you looking for this? `mService.getClass().getName()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get class name dynamically, you can use:

```
mService.getClass().getName();
```

If you want to get class name only, without *package*, you can use:

```
mService.getClass().getSimpleName();
```